# Realizing algebraic intersection number in 3-manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a conected, nonorientable 3-manifold, with a homology class $[K] \in H_{2}(M; \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})$ and a class $[\gamma] \in \pi_{1}(M)$ which have zero mod-2 algebraic intersection: $[K] \cdot [\gamma] = 0 \in \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

> > 1) Can one find representatives for these classes which have zero geometric intersection?
> >
> > 2) If so, can one choose them such that the representative for $K$ is the mod-2 fundamental class of an embedded surface?

Comment: Here's a simple counterexample. Let $M = M_1 \coprod M_2$ be the disjoint union of two copies of the same nonorientable 3-manifold, and let $K_i \subset M_i$ be a connected surface and $\gamma_i \subset M_i$ be a simple closed curve having odd algebraic intersection number. Then $K=K_1 \cup K_2$ and $\gamma=\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ have even algebraic intersection number. But there are no disjoint representatives homologous to $K$ and $\gamma$, because if there were then their intersections with $M_1$ would be homologous to $K_1$ and $\gamma_1$ and would have even intersection number.

Comment: Both can be done assuming that $M$ is connected.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that I am interested in the connected case. Can you elaborate on why this can be done in that case? I still haven't figured it out, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If $[K]$ is represented by some embedded surface $K$ and $[\gamma]$ by a loop $\gamma$ that intersects $K$ transversely in an even number of points, then consider two adjacent points of intersection on $\gamma$.  You can use the stretch of $\gamma$ between them to do surgery on the surface, cutting two small holes around the intersection points and then attaching a tube along the stretch of $\gamma$ that connects them.  This surface is homologous to the original $K$, and intersects $\gamma$ in two fewer points.  Repeat until there are 0 points of intersection.